# Should an engineering product research at a university be always released in a journal?

Tags: publications, journals, university, engineering

For example, a research team (we name it A) of a university makes an engineering product that they claim is capable of doing X, Y, and Z. Initially the product was not intended to be commercialized, only for research purposes, but eventually the product was commercialized. Then, the person at the same university, but not included in the research team said, "wow your product is amazing, but I'm a little doubtful of your claim, can I see the journal of the product?"

The question:

1. Must research team A release a journal of the commercialized product that the team has produced?
2. Is research team A wrong if they don't give the journal to that person?

Comment: If it's commercialized, then it is likely the founders of the company will not release their secret sauce unless it is patented.  Alternatively, they may keep it secret forever, e.g., Google's search algorithm.

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus, maybe expand that a bit to a full answer.

Comment: Do you mean publication in a journal?

Comment: @GoodDeeds yes, publication in a journal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have an established relationship with the developers and are willing to, perhaps, sign a non-disclosure agreement, I doubt that a request would be honored.

Sometimes the "work product" is a bit embarrassing ("mistakes were made") and sometimes it contains proprietary information and trade secrets. There may be things in it that lead to future developments and the team wants to keep those to themselves.

If the work is patented then you can read the patents themselves as they are intended to be public.